# Azure Autorest package dependency restore

Tags: c#, azure, swagger, nuget-package-restore, autorest

I am using Azure's Autorest to generate client code in C# from a particular Swagger json.

While the code is successfully generated, there is no packages.config/packages.json file that is generated with it to restore all the dependent nuget packages. I import the generated code files into an existing VS project and install the Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime package as instructed in the docs at https://github.com/Azure/autorest/blob/v1.0.1-20170504-2300-nightly/docs/client/proj-setup.md.

Anyway I can generate a package config file without manually installing the nuget packages? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dependency is a single package, and it's just the latest  Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.

Given that the move in the .NET standard is to having package references stored in the `.csproj` file, generating a files for the old standard is kind-of a dead end move at this point.

Comment: The code I generate has dependencies like System.Web.Http, System.Xml.Linq, etc. So I have to manually add these references to my project. Any way around it?

Comment: Usually, those references are already present in a new project. How are you creating your project? (and which VS are you using?)